# Как проверить символы в textBox после нажатия на кнопку?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, каким образом можно проверить содержимое `textBox` после нажатия на кнопку? В примере, похожий принцип, только при вводе значений:

```
private void textBoxIPm1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char ch = e.KeyChar;
    if (!char.IsNumber(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46 && ch != 110 && ch != '/')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

*upd_1:*

```
private void button1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char ch = e.KeyChar;
    if (!char.IsNumber(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46 && ch != 110 && ch != '/')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: а что именно вы хотите проверить??? создайте кнопку, и потом в коде обработчик событий на клик для этой кнопки (генерится двойным кликом по нажатию на кнопку в дизайнере). И в теле проверяйте ваш `texbox`

Comment: Если в `textBoxIPm1` ввести например буквы, должна появиться ошибка при нажатии на кнопку `button1`, но не получается сделать проверку содержимого в `textBoxIPm1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int result;
    if (int.TryParse(textBoxIPm1.Text, out result))
    {
        // если числа
    }
    else MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

Comment: `RoutedEventArgs` не могу найти в списке событий

Comment: Спасибо, не стал подписывать `Routed` думаю это от WPF формы